# How do you wire a usb type c female connector?

Tags: pcb, usb, soldering, usb-device, usb-c

I'm modifying my Nintendo controller, and I need to solder some stuff onto the **usb type c** **female** plug.  However, I noticed there are **five** pins, and I have **no idea** what a single one is. Could you explain what each pin is?

Sorry it's blurry; this is my usb c female plug:

[image: board]

Comment: It depends what pins the connector provides. Also, why are you trying to solder something to the connector pins? They break out neatly to nearby unused pads for components. And if you explained how are you trying to mod the controller, we could perhaps say if it is even possible or not. What are you trying to do, what do you want to achieve, which USB pins you need for that?

Comment: this looks like an XY question ... asking for help with a perceived solution to an unspecified problem, instead of asking about the problem ... why do you `need to solder some stuff`?

Comment: Five-pin USB connectors are USB-Bmicro, usually.   The USBc connectors may include Thunderbolt functions, and because they're reversible, the pin count is 24.   Maybe, for charge-only, there's some lower-count options.

Comment: @Whit3rd Thunderbolt on a game controller? Unlikely. The 5 pins are the minimum between connector and PCB for having USB2 interface, 2 for data, 2 for supplies, and 1 for Cable Connection. The connector interface likely has more pins than 5, but might not have 24 as high speed lines are unused.

Comment: I want to simply add some blue led lights, so I think I need the two power pins

Comment: @Noob But that does not require knowledge which pin is which. The power pins are visible so I can answer that. One more thing, because we don't know which device that is, is the Type-C port used as input or output? Is it a host to a device, or device to a host? Is it used for charging the console?

Comment: @Noob Do the ``blue led lights`` incorporate some circuitry (e.g. a series resistor or constant current drive) to allow them to be powered directly from the 5 V USB ``VBUS``? If unsure, [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/695048/edit) the question to include the part number for the led lights.

Comment: @Justme the plug is used as an output to send signals to the device,  which pins are the power supply?

Comment: @ChesterGillon yes, I'm gonna use some resistors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe from the blurry photo that pins of missing component L2 connect to ground and pins of missing component L1 connects to VBUS. These are the two widest tracks to the connector, so they must be the supply pins. The two narrower tracks are the USB data pair.

Feel free to measure yourself with a multimeter.

However, as this is a Type-C receptacle, there will be no voltage on connector unless a cable to another device is plugged in.

And since this is is Type-C, the voltage can be negotiated between the devices. You never told which device this is so the voltage it requests is unknown. Type-C currently supports up to 20V and 5A.

So just a warning that soldering blue LEDs to the VBUS and Ground pins of the connector may not be very useful as it always requires the cable to supply power, and you must know what voltages this device negotiates from the power source.

Comment: Thank you very much! It really helped :)